Accessing Aria Labels and Drop Down Menu Selection - Selenium Python
I am having trouble trying to automate selenium to go into the site settings and change the Insecure content drop down menu from blocked to allow. Every approach I take I get the error the element can not be found. There are 30 other drop-down menus and I believe aria labels to be the only reliable way to access the element. If there are any solutions whether it be with or without aria labels it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Inspect Screen
I have tried CSS.SElECTOR, CLASS_NAME, ID, XPATH, & ARIA-LABELS nothing seems to work.

Is it possible to share the link to the website?

It is a private website for my work. But if you click the site settings button to the right of the refresh button in the top left; it will lead you to the same site.

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

